# in mlrun, what is the difference between mlrun.auto_mount() vs mlrun.mount_v3io()

Tags: nuclio, mlrun

In mlrun, what is the difference between `mlrun.auto_mount()` vs `mlrun.mount_v3io()`?
when should `auto_mount()` or `mount_v3io()` be used?

Answer (score 2):

Before discussing these functions, it's important to note that MLRun has an auto-mount feature (don't confuse with the function) which means that every function created will get a default mount applied to it, with logic that is described in the documentation linked below. This means that unless you have a need to apply a mount with specific parameters or configuration, in most cases you shouldn't have to use any of these functions.

Please refer to https://docs.mlrun.org/en/stable/runtimes/function-storage.html for additional details on auto-mount.

As for these functions - both of them are modifiers that can be applied to an MLRun function to modify its execution spec in some way. Both should be used through the `apply` function, such as:

```
function.apply(mlrun.auto_mount())
```

The difference between them is that the `mount_v3io` function is used solely to create a `v3io` volume mount. The `auto_mount` modifier may create a `PVC` mount or a `v3io` mount based on environment variables - it tries to deduce the correct configuration to use.

Refer to https://docs.mlrun.org/en/stable/api/mlrun.platforms.html for documentation of these modifiers and others.